# virtual base classes initiailization

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, virtual-inheritance, ctor-initializer

I am working on a test and I have hard time to understand this one:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Car
{
 Car() : price(20000) {}
 Car(double b) : price(b*1.1) {}
 double price;
};
struct Toyota : public virtual Car 
{
 Toyota(double b) : Car(b) {}
};

struct Prius : public Toyota
{
 Prius(double b) : Toyota(b)  {}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 Prius p(30000);

 std::cout << p.price << std::endl;

 return 0;
}
```

The returned value is 20 000, but actually I do not not understand the why:

> All sub-objects representing virtual base classes are initialized by the constructor of the most derived class.  If the constructor of the most derived class does not specify a mem-initializer for a virtual base class V, then V's default construtor is called to initialize the virtual base class subobject.

And I tried different way to create a constructor in the derived class but I got errors from the compiler.

Does anyone provide an explanation and how to create such constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the mem-initializer for the (indirect) viirtual base:

```
Prius(double b) : Car(b), Toyota(b)  {}
```

See it [live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c497c37f7866b6f7).

Virtual inheritance makes sure that the virtual base will only exist once in the full object. For that, it *cannot* be the task of some intermediate base, which might not even be the only one asking for it, to initialize the virtual base: Which one should get the go-ahead?
Instead, the ctor is split in two: One for initializing everything but virtual bases, be they direct or indirect, and which is used by derived classes, and one first initializing the virtual bases, and then delegating the rest to the former, which is the one called for creating a full object.

Most compilers will warn if you get the order of mem-initializers wrong, so you aren't surprised later by what your code actually does. That was probably the error your compiler pointed out...

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the virtual inheritance:

```
struct Car
{
 Car() : price(20000) {}
 Car(double b) : price(b*1.1) {}
 double price;
 virtual ~Car() = default;
};

struct Toyota : public Car 
{
 Toyota(double b) : Car(b) {}
};
```

[Live Run](http://cpp.sh/3xs5e)

`Toyota` Is-a `Car` and does not need virtual inheritance.

Read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) about virtual inheritance if your test is about virtual inheritance